# Stats for Adsense ad units in DFP?

Tags: google-search-console, google-adsense, google-dfp, doubleclick-ad-exchange

I have a single page application and therefore my best option to use Adsense currently is to serve it through DoubleClick for Publishers.

I created an ad-unit, enabled it for AdSense.
Where will I be able to see how this ad unit is performing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you have it configured.   The usual way to show ads though DFP is to enable AdSense as the fallback for the slot.   In the inventory settings for the slot, you should have an option that looks like this:

[image]

In this case:

- DFP will report on your the performance of your ad slot
- DFP knows the exact revenue from this ad
- DFP knows about all channels that you assigned this ad
- Information about the slot and the channel won't make it to AdSense, so the AdSense reporting will not be very useful

---

The other way to do it is to paste your AdSense snippet into DFP and run your AdSense campaign as an "Order".   This is not the recommended way to run AdSense though DFP

- DFP won't get information about the costs (DFP reporting will be fairly useless).
- DFP won't be able to accurately predict how much AdSense would make and will not be able to choose between it and other ads as effectively.

If you run your AdSense ads this way, then you will check the stats through AdSense rather than through DFP.

---

No matter which way you run your ads, your payments will be handled through AdSense.   The total that you make from all your ads will be accurate in the AdSense reporting and your checks will be based on those figures.

Comment: Since I'm only using AdSense (no other ad networks) and like the AdSense interface more I'd prefer serving the AdSense code as orders. Are there any other downsides to this than the ones you listed?

Comment: Oh an how do I add my custom Adsense snippet into DFP?

Comment: I'm not sure why an SPA would be better served through DFP, but that might negate some of that.   Loading AdSense as an Order also makes the ads load slower, and I don't believe they load asynchronously.    To put in your snippet to DFP, you'd have to create an Order.

Comment: ok, slower loading sucks. If I find the time to I might test the difference.
SPAs have no page-reloads therefore vanilla-Adsense will only deliver two ads for the whole time the user spends on my page. Altering the AdSense-code to reload ads is prohibited though. Therefore DFP is used to incorporate Adsense in a SPA-page without the fear of getting banned.

Comment: You'll want the default fall-back option for DFP then.   Putting your ads in as an order could cause DFP to refresh them when the DFP ads are reloaded.